# How to use gsub with array element in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, gsub

I am trying to remove some speicial character from array but it showing error

```
undefined method gsub! for array 


 def get_names
   Company.find(@company_id).asset_types.pluck(:name).reject(&:nil?).gsub!(/([^,-_]/, '').map(&:downcase)
 end
```

Comment: Use `gsub`, not `gusb`.

Comment: Wrap it with `map`, just as you did with `downcase` (but you need to use the block)

Comment: I tried, it return false rather then the name

Comment: Arrays don't respond to `gsub!`, only strings do. To modify each string in an array of strings, you could use `ary.each { |str| str.gsub!(...) }`

Comment: To add to the above - use `gsub` instead of `gsub!`. The latter returns false when no substitution is made.

Comment: i tired this but still it not remove special character Company.find(@company_id).asset_types.pluck(:name).reject(&:nil?).each{|a| a.gsub!(/[!@%&"]/,'')&:downcase}

Answer (score 1):

As it was said arrays don't respond to `gsub!`. An array is a collection of items that you might process. To achieve what you want you should call `gsub` on each item. Notice the difference between [`gsub!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/String.html#method-i-gsub-21) and [`gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/String.html#method-i-gsub) methods. `gsub!` will modify a string itself and might return `nil` whereas `gsub` will just return a modified version of a string. In your case, I'd use `gsub`. Also, `reject(&:nil?)` might be replaced with [`compact`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Array.html#method-i-compact), it does the same thing. And you can call `downcase` inside the same block where you call `gsub`.

```rb
asset_types = Company.find(@company_id).asset_types.pluck(:name).compact
asset_types.map do |asset_type|
  asset_type.gsub(/([\^,-_])/, '').downcase
end
```

**UDP**

Your regexp `/([^,-_])/` means replace all characters that are not `,`, `-` or `_`. See [the documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Regexp.html)

> If the first character of a character class is a caret (^) the class is inverted: it matches any character except those named.

To make it work as expected you should escape `^`. So the regexp will be `/([\^,-_])/`.

There is [a website](https://rubular.com) where you can play with Ruby's regular expressions.

Comment: now it return only array of " " empty string and only show special character

Comment: how can i fix this

Comment: @MuhammadUsman Did it help?

Answer (score 1):

To put it simply without getting into other potential issues with your code, you are getting the error because `gsub` is only a valid `Method` in `Class: String`.  You are attempting to use it in `Class: Array`.

If you want to use gsub on your individual array elements, you must do 2 things:

1. Convert your individual array elements to strings (if they aren't strings already).
2. Use `gsub` on those individual strings

The above can be done any number of ways but those basics should directly address your core question.

For what its worth, I would typically use something like this:

```
new_array = old_array.map {|element| element.to_s.gsub(*args)}
```

In fact, you could simply change the last section of your existing code from:

```
....gsub(*args).map(&:downcase)
```

to:

```
....map {|x| x.to_s.gsub(*args).downcase}
```